# Is there any class in org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.model.api can be used for tailf:action?

Tags: java, opendaylight

I am working on a project which I need to parse the tailf:action in yang schema using opendaylight library. I try to find a class in org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.model.api which can be used to parse tailf:action. Then I can get input and output (normally they are list of leafs) from this class instance to do recursive processing. 
Anyone has idea whether there is a class in org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.model.api can support tailf:action ?

I show a tailf:action example as below.

Thanks in advance.

```
tailf:action set-ip-attributes {
        description "set ip";
        tailf:info "...";
        tailf:exec "/usr/local/a.py" {
          tailf:args "-c $(context) -p $(path)";
        }
        tailf:cli-mount-point "set";
        input {
          leaf ip {
            type inet:ip-address;
            mandatory true;
            description "IP Address of the session";
            tailf:info "IP Address of the session";
          }
          leaf attribute {
            type string;
            mandatory true;
            description "Name of the attribute";
            tailf:info "Name of the attribute";
          }
        }
        output {
          uses set-session-attribute;         
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Opendaylight only support "action" instead of "tailf:action". Below classes are used:
org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.model.api.ActionDefinition;
org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.model.api.ActionNodeContainer;